# Insert HTML Form with Variable Rows via PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form that allows users to add and delete rows. I am using POST to send the values to a PHP page to insert values into a MySQL database. I am able to submit static rows however cannot figure out how to loop through and insert all rows on the form since it is variable (users can add or remove rows). Can someone please advise how I can accomplish inserting all rows via PHP. **I know how to establish a connection, that is not an issue.** Any help provided would be greatly appreciated.

My HTML form:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="/SubmitTest.php" method="post">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="mytable">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>{{$index+1}}</td>

          <td><input id="{{'CustomerName-'+$index}}" name="CustomerName[]"></td>

          <td><input id="{{'Employee-'+$index}}" name="Employee[]"></td>

          <td><input id="{{'Cash-'+$index}}" name="CashAmt[]"></td>

          <td><input id="{{'Check-'+$index}}" name="CheckAmt[]"></td>

          <td><input id="{{'Total-'+$index}}" name="Total[]"></td>

          <td><input id="{{'Invoice-'+$index}}" name="Invoice[]"></td>

          <td><button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <div class="new row"><button class="btn btn-success" type="button">Add Row</button></div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There's no PHP code here, so this isn't a Stack Overflow question but some kind of work order. If you haven't done a lot of PHP and want to build out a back-end for this, evaluate the various [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) out there and pick one that suits your style and needs. [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) is particularly easy to get going with and well-supported here.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all the input parameters.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO yourTable (customerName, employee, cashAmt, checkAmt, total, invoice)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssiiis", $customerName, $employee, $cashAmt, $checkAmt, $total, $invoice)
foreach ($_POST['CustomerName'] as $i => $customerName) {
    $employee = $_POST['Employee'][$i];
    $cashAmt = $_POST['CashAmt'][$i];
    $checkAmt = $_POST['CheckAmt'][$i];
    $totel = $_POST['Totel'][$i];
    $invoice = $_POST['Invoice'][$i];
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```

Comment: What happens in the event that one of those isn't a required and they skip for example employee? The bind/prepare would fail.

Comment: You can add validation checks before calling execute.

Comment: Or he can user usr_function and send in parameter references dynamically

Comment: I'm not sure what `usr_function` is. Did you mean `call_user_function()`? How would that be an improvement? Then you have SQL injection problems.

Comment: Not if you use dynamically bound parameters with it. You can use call_user_function to run the bind parameter portion of a prepared statement, then only use the parameters that were supplied

Comment: Except for checkboxes, the form will submit values for every row. If they don't fill in a field it will be submitted with an empty string as the value.

Comment: Maybe you should post an answer showing what you're suggesting. I'm not seeing how you would call it dynamically like that. Maybe you could do it with `call_user_function_array()` after filling in the array dynamically based on which inputs were supplied.

Comment: that's what I'm getting at

Comment: I don't see the point. If the field is required, you should just skip the row if it's not supplied. If it's not required, you the value will be a blank string, and you'll insert that value into the DB. No need to do anything dynamic.

Comment: Thank you so much Barmar, I am rather new to PHP and especially new to Prepared Statements.